# Virtualbox share mounted on user directory is unable to access .ICEauthority

Tags: linux, virtualbox, permissions, mount

I am trying to mount my virtualbox shared folder on /home/user but when I login it says that it could not update the .ICEauthority file. The file is owned by me and it's permissions are 744, and I tried setting the permission to 777 but it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right, you need to get to the console, log in and check if ".ICEauthority" is owned by you:

```
ls -al .ICEauthority
```

If it's not, but by root possibly, change it to you:

```
sudo chown USERNAME:USERNAME .ICEauthority
```

And then just go back to login screen and try to log in.